# How to convert the data extracted from a file to bytes in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.4

I am a newbie to python scripting. I have to extract data line by line from a text file and then convert each line of data received to bytes or bytearray in my .py file.

i am able to extract the data from the file line by line, but not able to convert that to bytes. 
The text in the file is as follows:

```
04/nov/14 09:15:30 4.6 2.3

05/nov/14 09:30:45 3.2

06/nov/14 10:00:00 1.2 3.4 5.6
```

I am not very sure how to use bitArray or bytes/bytearray to the data for conversion. 
I am sorry I have no code to show here other than file read operation.

```
file_read = open("read_me.txt", 'r')

for line_read in file_read:

        if line_read != "\n":

                print(line_read[:-1])

file_read.close()
```

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line that you're getting is now a Unicode string. To convert this to bytes you can do:

```
line_read_bytes = line_read.encode('UTF-8')
```

which will give you the string encoded in UTF-8.

You can also create a bytearray using:

```
line_read_bytearray = bytearray(line_read, 'UTF-8')
```