# How to encrypt text using RSA algo

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I need to encrypt texts written in a file and decrypt it, without using the PyCrypto library. The file will contain string type data. Now I want to convert the strings to int numbers so that I can apply the RSA keys on the integer values. But I did not find any tutorial on how to convert texts into int. How to convert the strings into its integer value and Is there any better way of doing this? then how? Thank you.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792911/how-to-convert-the-data-extracted-from-a-file-to-bytes-in-python, I think, text can be converted to bytes

Comment: Is it for learning or a real application? Please note RSA itself is intended to encrypt around 200-300 bytes of data, otherwise search for hybrid encryption

Comment: [`cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/) supports RSA encryption, and it doesn't require int-only input

Comment: This is actually for my school project and  I cannot use the built-in functions

Comment: Your title doesn't really match your question. The title implies you're asking about RSA encryption, but the question you actually ask is how to convert an arbitrary string to an integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Reversibly encode alphanumeric string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420705/python-reversibly-encode-alphanumeric-string-to-integer)

Comment: RSA can't be used to encrypt arbitrary files (only data smaller than the key size) -> use hybrid encryption AES + RSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had this project, and I did this:

First what you will need is to read the datas from the text file and save it to a list. You can use `.split()` which will do this : 
If the file contains only one line like this

`hello !` it will make it as

`list_of_the_file['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', '!']`

Now as you have a list of all the letters that the file contains serially, you can use the `ord()` which will generate a unique value for each type of character for example `a` or more precisely ord(a) will give you the value `97` and it will return `97` only for the `a` present in the list not for any other character. Then you can apply the keys on that integer value and can store it in a list or a file. Hope this will help.